# python statement with `or` inside square brackets

Tags: python

This is a code snippet I pasted from a setup.py python file. I am new to python and don't understand this `build_args` variable. Could someone give me some explanation for that?

```
build_args = [NINJA or MAKE]

# control the number of concurrent jobs
if self.jobs is not None:
    build_args.extend(['-j', str(self.jobs)])

subprocess.check_call(build_args)
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: `or` when used in this way means "use the second value if the first one evaluates to false".  So if the value of `NINJA` is `None` or `""` or `0`, etc., the value of `MAKE` will be used instead.  The brackets are irrelevant; they are just using the result of that statement to initialize a new `list`.

Answer (score 1):

build_args' instantiation is simply *evaluating a logical boolean OR statement* inside of the list a list structure. After the OR statement has been evaluated there will simply be a single boolean value stored in build_args. (props to ukemi, beat me to the punch)

Since it was also included in the code snippet I'd add that info for '.extend()' following can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Essentially .extend() then just appends all items of an iterable structure on the end of the list, so build_args' content would then be `[<boolean>, '-j', <job_string>]`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
build_args = [NINJA or MAKE]
```

- If `NINJA` is "truthy", then `build_args = [NINJA]`
- If `NINJA` is "falsy", then `build_args = [MAKE]`

---

---

**Note: Python's Truthy and Falsy - generalized Booleans**

In python there are [other values](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) equivalent to `True` and `False`, other than the booleans themselves:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false:
>
> - `False`
> - `None`
> - numeric zero of all types
> - empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets)
>
> All other values are interpreted as true.

---

Truth table for `or`:

| x | y | x `or` y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | x |
| True | False | x |
| False | True | y |
| False | False | y |